# Not able to scrape a web page with multiple html tags

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I did thoroughly searched at stackoverflow but could not find a suitable solution. I am scraping a legacy web site  and I want to extract all the labels and input names. The html format of the old webpage is something like this

```
<div class="labellong">First Name</div>
<INPUT class="input-l"  name="firstname">

<div class="labellong">Last Name</div>
<INPUT class="input-l"  name="lastname">

<div class="labellong">Gender</div>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>

<table>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td width="174">User Name</td>
        <td width="888"><input name="username" value="" id="username" class="input-m" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="174">User Account</td>
        <td width="888"><input name="useraccount" value="" id="uaseraccount" class="input-m" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to extract output using python with beautifulsoup as

```
First Name, firstname 
Last Name, lastname 
Gender, gender 
User Name, username 
User Account, useraccount
```

I did tried findall method but has failed,  as i need label(text) and input tag name together, are there solutions to scrap with multiple html tags with label text? Thanks

I am new to webpage scraping and here is code i did tried

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request as urllib2

f = open("g:\output.txt", "w")
errFile = open("g:\error.txt", "w")

url = "file:///g://pharmacy.htm"
file = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(file)


for message1 in soup.findAll(["div", {"class": "labellong"}, "input", {"class": "input-l"}, "td"]):
    outText = message1.get_text()
    f.write( outText + '\n')


f.close()
errFile.close()
```

Comment: I have update the post with code i tried with,  should I use next_element  or next_siblings to get desired output?

Answer (score -1):

The solution I would try is to select the sibling https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling

So first find the labels then with each label find the sibling

**Edit**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("/Projects/python/webscraping/web.html"),"html5lib")

for div in soup.findAll(["div", {"class": "labellong"}]):
    labelName = div.get_text()
    for sibling in div.next_siblings:
        if (sibling.name == "input"):
            inputName = sibling['name']
            break
    print labelName, inputName

for row in soup.findAll(["tr"]):
    labelName = None
    inputName = None
    for td in row:
        if (td.name == 'td'):
            if (not labelName): # labelName not yet set
                labelName = td.get_text()
            else: # second td so inputName
                inputName = td.contents[0]['name']
                print labelName, inputName
```

Comment: thanks, i did try with the next_siblings and seems not working in my case, next i will try to parse through all tags by using next_element

Comment: @AnuNag did you manage to find a solution? I edited my answer to how how you could use sibling